# Post request to Facebook marketing API via urlFetchApp returns "Unsupported post request"

Tags: javascript, facebook-marketing-api

I am having some issues sending a post request to an ad in my linked Facebook Business Manager account from within a Google Ads Script. I have an app set up and I'm able to send post and get requests over the Graph API using the same user access token, so I'm confident this is not an issue with my permission scope.

The aim is to activate/deactivate an ad, however I'm getting `error 100 subcode 33`: `Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'xxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation`

I've tried various ways of sending the status update (as a payload and within the url itself as below).

```
function callFBAPI(ad, status) {
    var options = {
    method: "POST",
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  fbUrl =
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/" +
    "ad_id_code" +
    "?status=" +
    status +
    "&access_token=" +
    encodeURIComponent(fbUserCode);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fbUrl, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log("Data successfully received by FB marketing API");
  } else {
    Logger.log("Response code: " + response.getResponseCode());
    Logger.log("Error sending data to FB marketing API: " + response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

Comment: There isn't any POST data in your POST request. Can you show your payload code?

Comment: My understanding is that with the Graph API you add your request in the URI, here it's the `"?status=" + status` part

Comment: Yes, but then why send a POST request? If all information is in the URL and there's nothing in the body, you're probably supposed to send a GET request instead.